# How to render "would have to" in French?

Tags: choix-de-mot, temps-grammatical

J'aurais dû + infinitive verb = 'I should have..."

I.e. j'aurais dû laisser mon passport à la maison.
      J'aurais dû utiliser ton stylo au lieu du mien.

In the above cases, both actions refer to a regret that manifested after having done another thing e.g. taking your passport with you. 
However, if rendered as a hypothetical, can the construction also mean "I would have to..."?

I.e: 
Are you sure he arrived late yesterday. Because if that was the case, I'd have to fire him.
"Vous étes sûr qu'il est arrivè en retard hier? Parce que si c'etait le cas, j'aurais dû le virer."

"Can you tell me why my car isn't working? No, sorry, I would have to take a look, first?"
Est-ce que vous pouvez m'expliquer pourquoi ma voiture ne marche plus bien? Non, J'aurais dû jeter un œil."

I realize that the above examples could also take future tense i.e. "will have to..." and am wondering if French has a construction that equates to "would have to."

Comment: Not that relevant but `.i.e` means `id est` ( 'which is' in latin, used as 'which means' ) ; you're apparently using it to provide examples, which would be ( -> 'devrais être' in french :) )  `e.g.` : `exempli gratia` ( example provided )

Answer (score 3):

To modify your examples:

> Are you sure he arrived late yesterday? Because if that was the case, I'd have to fire him.
>   "Vous êtes sûr qu'il est arrivé en retard hier ? Parce que si c'était le cas, <strike>j'aurais dû le virer</strike> **il me faudrait le virer**, ou **il faudrait que je le vire**."
>
> "Can you tell me why my car isn't working? No, sorry, I would have to take a look, first?"
>   Est-ce que vous pouvez m'expliquer pourquoi ma voiture ne marche plus bien ? Non, <strike>J'aurais dû jeter un œil</strike> **il me faudrait y jeter un  œil**, ou **il faudrait que j'y jette un  œil**."

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think it should be "that became manifest " or, as well,  "that manifested itself"?

In the above cases, both actions refer to a regret that became manifest after having done another thing e.g. taking your passport with you. However, if rendered as a hypothetical, can the construction also mean "i would have to..."?

> Je suis allé camper dans les bois près de chez moi; j'avais glissé mon passeport dans mon sac avant de partir et je l'ai perdu; j'aurais dû laisser mon passeport à la maison.

However, if instead of considering an action itself we consider the hypothesis of it, can the construction also mean "i would have to..."?

No, it can't be used: it corresponds to no modality in this case.

If you make the action hypothetical and want to formulate something the modality of which corresponds to "I would have to" you can use the following form.

> Si je devais aller camper dans les bois près de chez moi j'aurais à laisser mon passeport à la maison.

However, an unambiguous rendering would be as follows.

… je croirais devoir laisser mon passeport à la maison.

---

I.e: Are you sure he arrived late yesterday. Because if that was the case, I'd have to fire him. "Vous étes sûr qu'il est arrivè en retard hier? Parce que si c'etait le cas, j'aurais dû le virer."

Not exact

Parce que si c'était le cas, je devrais le virer." *ou*

Parce que si c'était le cas, j'aurais à le virer."

Pour que la dernière phrase soit correcte il faut changer le temps de la phrase précédente.

"Vous étes sûr qu'il est arrivé en retard hier? Parce que si ça avait été  le cas, j'aurais dû le virer."

And then "**j'aurais dû le virer**" means something else, not any more "**I'd have to fire him**" but "**I should/would have fired him**". (*firing expected*)

(English) Are you sure he arrived late yesterday. Because if that had been the case, I  should have fired him.

---

Not exact

"Can you tell me why my car isn't working? No, sorry, I'd have to take a look, first?" Est-ce que vous pouvez m'expliquer pourquoi ma voiture ne marche plus bien? Non, J'aurais dû jeter un œil."

Est-ce que vous pouvez m'expliquer pourquoi ma voiture ne marche plus bien? "Non, Je dois d'abord la regarder."  *ou*

"Non, Je dois y jeter un (coup d')œil avant." *ou* "Non je dois d'abord y jeter un œil."

You can also use the future tense.

"Non, il faudra que d'abord (je la regarde.)/(j'y jette un œil.)"

If the subject is changed the future tense can be used with "devoir" and the meaning is equivalent.

"Non, il devra d'abord y avoir une inspection de la mécanique."

The form "Je devrai y jeter un coup d'œil." n'est vraiment pas utilisable comme on ne sait pas, la prononciation de "devrai" et de "devrais" étant la même, duquel il s'agit; d'ailleur, peut être pour cette raison on n'utilise pas ou peu "je devrai" et à la place on entend "j'aurai à"; les autres personnes sont utilisées normalement (tu devras, il devra,…).